# Ember-cli-simple auth and ember-cli-simple-auth-torii how to make them work together

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am little confused on how to use ember-simple-auth with torii

I am using ember-cli-simple-auth and ember-cli-simple-auth-torii
i am getting below mentioned error
dont know waht i am missing
**`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: No application initializer named 'torii'`**

routes.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login');
  this.route('application');
  this.route('protected');
});
```

app/routes/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicatonRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicatonRouteMixin);
```

app/route/login

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export
default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        // action to trigger authentication with Facebook
        authenticateWithFacebook: function () {
            this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:torii', 'facebook-oauth2');
        }
    }
});
```

app/routes/protected

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend( AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

app/initializers/torii-initializer.js

```
import ToriiAuthenticator from 'simple-auth-torii/authenticators/torii';
export default Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    // register the Torii authenticator so the session can find them
    container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:torii', ToriiAuthenticator);
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
  }
});
```

index.html

```
window.AuthENV = {
    {
        ENV
    }
};
window.EmberENV = window.AuthENV.EmberENV;
window.ENV = window.ENV || {};
window.ENV['torii'] = {
    providers: {
        'facebook-oauth2': {
            apiKey: '63125ss',
            redirectUri: document.location.href
        }
    }
};
```

login template

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<a {{action "authenticateWithFacebook"}}> login</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the torii Ember CLI Addon as well as that's currently not automatically included when you install ember-cli-simple-auth-torii:

```
npm install --save-dev torii
```